# Trimming first characters of a line to match length of a second line

Tags: text, awk, trim, fastq

I am playing with some fastq files trimming specific sequences from the 2nd line of the fastq sequence:

Input example:

```
@D00733:159:CA65UANXX:8:1214:11297:78554
GTTTTACACAATTATACGGACTTTATCCGCTTTTGTGCCTCTTTAATTTC
+
BBCCCEGGGGGGGFGEGGGDGGGGGGGGGGGGGGFGGGGGGGGGGGGEGG
@D00733:159:CA65UANXX:8:1214:11297:78555
TATGATTAGATGCGGATTGATCTGATCGGGACTGATTTTTTTTAGGGATT
+
BBCCCEGGGGGGGFGEGGGDGGGGGGGGGGGGGGFGGGGGGGGGGGGEGG
```

I trim from the sequence the subsequence 'TTATACGGACTTTATC' and anything that it is before of it with:

```
sed 's/^.*TTATACGGACTTTATC//' in.fastq > in2.fastq
```

The result looks like:

```
@D00733:159:CA65UANXX:8:1214:11297:78554
CGCTTTTGTGCCTCTTTAATTTC
+
BBCCCEGGGGGGGFGEGGGDGGGGGGGGGGGGGGFGGGGGGGGGGGGEGG
@D00733:159:CA65UANXX:8:1214:11297:78555
TATGATTAGATGCGGATTGATCTGATCGGGACTGATTTTTTTTAGGGATT
+
BBCCCEGGGGGGGFGEGGGDGGGGGGGGGGGGGGFGGGGGGGGGGGGEGG
```

Which could be an efficient way to trim the beginning of the 4th line in the entry (quality) to match the length of the 2nd one (sequence)? Each line is delimited by \n characters and each entry consists of 4 lines (identifier, sequence, +, quality).

Expected output:

```
@D00733:159:CA65UANXX:8:1214:11297:78554
CGCTTTTGTGCCTCTTTAATTTC
+
GGGGGGGFGGGGGGGGGGGGEGG
@D00733:159:CA65UANXX:8:1214:11297:78555
TATGATTAGATGCGGATTGATCTGATCGGGACTGATTTTTTTTAGGGATT
+
BBCCCEGGGGGGGFGEGGGDGGGGGGGGGGGGGGFGGGGGGGGGGGGEGG
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the non *"bio-physio-fastqatious"* amongst us (that's me), your lines always come in groups of four. The first of a group starts with `@`. You want to find something (which varies from one run to the next) on line 2 of any group and, if you find it, remove it along with as many characters as necessary from the start of the 4th line in order to make the length of the 4th line match that of the 2nd line of the group. Correct? Or hopeless?

Comment: Perfect explanation of the problem!

Comment: Excellent! @EdMorton should be able to solve it for us now ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR%4==2{s=match($0,/TTATACGGACTTTATC/)+RLENGTH} NR%4~/[02]/{$0=substr($0,s)} 1' file
@D00733:159:CA65UANXX:8:1214:11297:78554
CGCTTTTGTGCCTCTTTAATTTC
+
GGGGGGGFGGGGGGGGGGGGEGG
@D00733:159:CA65UANXX:8:1214:11297:78555
TATGATTAGATGCGGATTGATCTGATCGGGACTGATTTTTTTTAGGGATT
+
BBCCCEGGGGGGGFGEGGGDGGGGGGGGGGGGGGFGGGGGGGGGGGGEGG
```

Comment: Wow, that's amazing

Comment: I don't wish to be critical, now that you have so kindly and succinctly solved this, but you seem to be just looking for 2nd of every 4 lines, rather than the second line starting from one beginning with `@`, so won't it go wrong if there is a blank line anywhere in the file, or a single header line? It's ok if it's a pain to ruggedise - I'm just asking.

Comment: Correct. If that can happen we need the OP to fix their sample input.